# Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate while service type was registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

What's wrong with my dependency injection? I followed C# tutorials, but it seems like I'm missing something.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICliente _cliente;

    public HomeController(ICliente ClienteService)
    {
        _cliente = ClienteService;
    }
}

public interface ICliente
{
    public void TestarCliente();
}

public class ClienteService : ICliente
{
    public void TestarCliente() { ... }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

builder.Services.AddTransient<ICliente, ClienteService>();
```

Error from the browser

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Lanchonete.Interfaces.ICliente' while attempting to activate 'Lanchonete.Controllers.HomeController'.
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need add the service to the container before you invoke app.Run()

i.e.:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICliente, ClienteService>(); // Move this here
app.Run();
```

Comment: @Nat Also some useful information on what instance state you want to store your objects in the DI container. https://www.dofactory.com/code-examples/csharp/service-lifetimes